# Casting integer value to String Enum in typescript returns undefined

Tags: typescript, enums

My API returns string enums. So I have registered my enum as such.

```js
export enum MyEnum {
    Unknown = 'Unknown',
    SomeValue = 'SomeValue',
    SomeOtherValue = 'SomeOtherValue',
  }
```

Now we get an integer value from another source which we can not change. This needs to be mapped to MyEnum at some point and checked in a condition. Using code below should work but it returns undefined for some reason.

```js
const myIntValue = 1;
const myEnumValue = MyEnum[myIntValue]; // This returns undefined..

var myCondition = myEnumValue === MyEnum.SomeValue; // Is false because undefined != MyEnum.SomeValue
```

How do I get the Enum value in typescript to either cast to the correct enum value or at least to work for my condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

First one, you can modify your `enum`.

```js
enum MyEnum {
    Unknown = 1,
    SomeValue,
    SomeOtherValue,
}

const myIntValue = 1;
const myEnumValue = MyEnum[myIntValue]; // string
```

If you remove `1` from `MyEnum` definition, it will start from `0`.

Personally, I don't like this solution because `numerical enum` is not the best choice.

Consider this example:

```js
const foo = (en: MyEnum) => 42

foo(99999) // ok
```

Second option.

You can map integers to enum using a tuple:

```js
const enum MyEnum {
    Unknown = 'Unknown',
    SomeValue = 'SomeValue',
    SomeOtherValue = 'SomeOtherValue',
}

const MapEnum = [MyEnum.Unknown, MyEnum.SomeValue, MyEnum.SomeOtherValue] as const;

const result = MapEnum[1] // MyEnum.SomeValue
```

Keep in mind, that `enum`/`object` keys are unordered, so it is not safe to create such tuple dynamicaly.

**UPDATE**

> Second option works although it is more error prone ...

```js
enum MyEnum {
    Unknown = 'Unknown',
    SomeValue = 'SomeValue',
    SomeOtherValue = 'SomeOtherValue',
}

type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

const MapEnum: TupleUnion<MyEnum> = [MyEnum.Unknown, MyEnum.SomeValue, MyEnum.SomeOtherValue,];
```

No way you will forget some value

Alternative way without permutation:

```js
enum MyEnum {
    Unknown = 'Unknown',
    SomeValue = 'SomeValue',
    SomeOtherValue = 'SomeOtherValue',
}

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
    k: infer I
) => void
    ? I
    : never;

// Credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
    U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
    ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
    : [T, ...A];

type Result = UnionToArray<MyEnum>

const MapEnum: UnionToArray<MyEnum> = [MyEnum.Unknown, MyEnum.SomeValue, MyEnum.SomeOtherValue,];
```

More examples you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/union-array)

Comment: First option is not an option because the main API still return's strings. So the string enum requirement is more important. Second option works although it is more error prone if forgotten to update both enum and map. Thanks!

Comment: The typescript documentation do state that a string enum will be auto incremented starting from zero so I do find it odd that I can't cast it to the correct value based on an int.